# How to check whether user's input is correct or not (for a quiz)

Tags: javascript, html, css

How to check whether user's input is correct or not (for a quiz)?

For instance, the quiz is "where is this food from?" and there are 4 different images which javascript chooses from to display and make the user guess. the first picture is from `Turkey`, then `Greece`, `India`, then `Mongolia`. if the `Turkey` picture comes up, and the user types `Turkey`, how do I check whether the user's input is correct?

I am using a **text input** for this function, not a javascript modal.

Code for the input box

```
<input class="end" id="guess" onclick="guess()"placeholder="Make a Guess!" style="border-radius: 31px; width: 20%; height: 62px; line-height: 1.2; color: mediumslateblue; padding: 0 35px; font-size: 16px; border-style: 7px solid yellow; visibility: hidden;">
```

Answer (score 3):

You haven't shared much of your code for us to dive into.
From what I am guessing, you need to replace "onclick" with "oninput" event.
oninput event is called everytime a new character is typed on the input tag.

You can compare  the input field value with the answers.

```js
const guess = () => {
    let input = document.querySelector("#guess");
    if(input.value.toLowerCase() === "turkey"){
        console.log("Correct");
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="guess" oninput="guess()">
```

Answer (score 1):

Just match the picture's filename to a user's input. Should use multiple choices input (drop down) to avoid typo error.

Answer (score 0):

Create a database with questions + answers, than you can compare user's answer to expected one:

```js
const data = {
  question: 0,
  db: [
    {
      answer: "turkey",
      img: "tr"
    },
    {
      answer: "greese",
      img: "gr"
    },
    {
      answer: "india",
      img: "in"
    },
    {
      answer: "mongolia",
      img: "mn"
    },
  ]
};
function guess()
{
  const txt = document.getElementById("guess").value.trim().toLowerCase();
  document.getElementById("result").textContent = txt == data.db[data.question].answer ? "correct" : "wrong";
  
}

function question()
{
  data.question = Math.floor(Math.random() * data.db.length); //pick random question
  document.getElementById("question").src = "https://cdn.ipregistry.co/flags/noto/" + data.db[data.question].img + ".png";
  document.getElementById("hint").textContent = data.db[data.question].answer;
}

question()
```

```html
<img id="question" onclick="question()">

<input class="end" id="guess" placeholder="Make a Guess!" style="border-radius: 31px; width: 20%; height: 62px; line-height: 1.2; color: mediumslateblue; padding: 0 35px; font-size: 16px; border: 7px solid yellow;">
<button  onclick="guess()">Answer</button>
<div>
Hint: <span id="hint"></span>
</div>
Result: <span id="result"></span>
```

Comment: Thanks 
When I do this code on a separate document, the image doesn't show up though. Why?

Comment: If you change code nobody can answer without seeing it...

Comment: This doesn't allow me to add code. Do you have a Discord or somewhere where I can send the code?

Comment: Do you have a link to a JFIDDLE or something?

Comment: You can use https://jsfiddle.net/ or https://codepen.io/

Comment: No everything works except the https://cdn.ipregistry.co/flags/noto/ (the showing up of your specific image). What should I replace that with ?

Comment: Replace it with the address of your images...(sorry, I don't understand what is the confusion here)

Comment: Where do I put the address of my images? Sorry I am not udnerstanding

Comment: hello is there a way to make it a variable/array instead of a constant?